# Strings Based on Variables

Tags: c, string

Say I have variables `double x, y, z;` and I want to make a txt file with a name based on those variables e.g. "GenericName_x_y_z.txt".

How would I create the string?

I know functions like `printf("GenericName_%.2f_%.2f_%.2f.txt", x, y, z)` you can do, but how would I define a string like that, not just print it?

So then I can use

```
char filename[] = "GenericName_%.2f_%.2f_%.2f.txt";

FILE* fPointer;
fPointer = fopen(filename, "w");
```

I'm sorry the phrasing is really terrible and its probably a really basic thing I'm not getting!

Thanks

Comment: Your title is somewhat misleading. You're not looking for filenames based on variables but for _strings_ basd on variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html):

```
char filename[128];
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "GenericName_%.2f_%.2f_%.2f.txt", x, y, z);
```